# Advanced JMeter Looping

Tags: javascript, http, jmeter, jsr223

Let's say I have a user-defined paramater `bodies` which is a space-delimited list of arbitrary length. I need to create a loop of HTTP requests based on the length of `bodies` and use its content.

For example if `bodies=a b c`, then I need to make a HTTP POST request using `a` in the header, then another using `b` in the header, and so on.

How can I do this in JMeter? So far, I've been able to use a JSR223 Sampler to set a variable `NUM_ITERATIONS` (would be 3 in this case), but I don't know how to loop using the correct parameter in each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can control how does your "bodies" variable look like you could transform it into something like:

```
bodies_1=a
bodies_2=b
bodies_3=c
```

and use [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) to iterate all the elements.

---

One of the possible ways:

1. Add Loop Controller to your Thread Group and put `${__groovy(vars.get('bodies').split(' ').size(),)}` expression into "Loop Count" stanza
2. Add [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler as a child of the Loop Controller
3. Add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler
4. Refer the value from the user-defined parameter as

   ```
   ${__groovy(vars.get('bodies').split(' ')[vars.get('__jm__Loop Controller__idx') as int],)}
   ```

   where required.

   [image: JMeter Groovy Demo]

References:

- [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)
- [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) aka `vars`
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)